# Are the default styles of pseudo-elements different from those of their respective original elements?

Tags: css, default, pseudo-element

Do the default CSS styles of pseudo-elements (like `::after` and `::before`) differ from the default styles of the elements they are derived from? If so, are there anys resource containing a full listing of how they differ?

For instance, while heading elements (like h1) have a display property of block by default, does adding an `::after` property to an h element change this default property?

I know in most any particular instances it can be discovered by experiment, but I'm more interested in a means of referencing or discerning these differences, if any, without the need to experiment with each individual instance.

Comment: I think by default its all just inline content like text

Comment: No, [It is inline by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: The pseudo-element is treated like a child of the element, and styled accordingly.

Comment: Hi Blazemonger. If that's true, then maybe the reason inline display properties apply in the example I gave is that the content you give to the pseudo-element to make it appear is text and, therefore, inline content; but the rest of the styles are inherited as you said. Can someone confirm this?